# Algorithm for testing all mathematical order

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I want to implement, that the User can input a Array of `int`s (`int[]`), and a desired `target`.

Then the program should be able to test *all possibilities* in *add*, *subtract*, *multiply* and *divide*, and return true, if any possibilities are given.

**Example:**

```
int[] = {1, 4, 6, 3}, target = 8
```

(Program test everything, from `1+4+6+3` till `1/4/6/3`)

**Desired result**

```
1+4+6-3
```

is the correct answer, since `1+4+6-3 == 8`

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question, then?

Comment: I want to know an algorithem, which does exactlly that

Comment: As usual, many rules are missing. Are parenthesis allowed ? Are there operator priorities ? Is inexact division allowed (e.g. 7/3) ? Can an intermediate result be a fraction (e.g. (1/3)x6= 2) ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry, first time here. Yes operator priorities exist, 7/3 is not allowed, and no () are allowed/used either

Comment: Don't worry, it is not you. Every single guy asking such questions forgets to state the problem formally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try *brute force* - we have just few formulae (`3**4 == 81` of them) to test. First, let's generate all formlae:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

...

private static IEnumerable<string> Formulae(int[] numbers) {
  char[] alphabet = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' };

  int[] current = new int[numbers.Length - 1];

  do {
    yield return string.Concat(numbers
      .Select((d, i) => $"{(i > 0 ? alphabet[current[i - 1]].ToString() : "")}{d}"));

    for (int i = 0; i < current.Length; ++i)
      if ((current[i] = (current[i] + 1) % alphabet.Length) != 0)
        break;
  }
  while (!current.All(i => i == 0));
}
```

then we `Compute` each formula:

```
private static string Solve(int[] numbers, int target) {
  using (DataTable table = new DataTable()) {
    foreach (string formula in Formulae(numbers)) {
      try {
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(table.Compute(formula, null));

        if (result == target)
          return $"{formula} = {target}";
      }
      catch (DivideByZeroException) {
        ;
      }
    }
  }

  return "No solution";
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.Write(Solve(new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 3 }, 8));
```

**Outcome**:

```
1+4+6-3 = 8
```

You need just a little modification, if you want to get *all solutions*:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> AllSolutions(int[] numbers, int target) {
  using (DataTable table = new DataTable()) {
    foreach (string formula in Formulae(numbers)) {
      int result; 

      try {
        result = Convert.ToInt32(table.Compute(formula, null));
      }
      catch (DivideByZeroException) {
        continue;
      }

      if (result == target)
        yield return $"{formula} = {target}";
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  AllSolutions(new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 3 }, 8)));
```

**Outcome:**

```
1+4+6-3 = 8
1*4*6/3 = 8
```

**Edit:** in the implementation above I used *integer division*, e.g.

```
1 / 4 == 0
```

if you want to use *floating point division*, i.e.

```
1.0 / 4.0 = 0.25
```

you should slightly modify the code:

```
// note ".0" in the very end of the Select 
private static IEnumerable<string> Formulae(int[] numbers) {
  ...
  yield return string.Concat(numbers
    .Select((d, i) => $"{(i > 0 ? alphabet[current[i - 1]].ToString() : "")}{d}.0"));
  ...
}

private static IEnumerable<string> AllSolutions(int[] numbers, 
                                                int target, 
                                                double tolerance = 1e-8) {
  using (DataTable table = new DataTable()) {
    foreach (string formula in Formulae(numbers)) {
      double result = Convert.ToDouble(table.Compute(formula, null));

      // Compare with tolerance
      if (Math.Abs(result - target) < tolerance)
        yield return $"{formula} = {target}";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Comparing a double and an int for equality is not going to end well...

Comment: @Dialecticus: agree, `int` is better

Comment: Does this code ignore formulas with parentheses, such as `(1+3)*(6-4)`?

Comment: Right, but we still have have a problem with integer division, so 1+1+1/3 will be equal 2, because Compute sees only integers. But if we turn numbers to double then Compute("1.0+1.0+1.0/3.0") would return two and a third as double, which would again be rounded to 2 by ToInt32. Can't win...

Comment: @Dialecticus: it depends how we treat division. In my code we have *integer* division, `1/3 == 0`. In case we have to deal with floating point, `1.0/3.0 == 0.33333...` we have to modify `Formulae` and in the `Solution` switch to `double result = Convert.ToDouble(...)`. Finally, compare with *tolerance*: `if (Math.Abs(result - target) < 1e-8) ...`

Comment: The comparison to 1e-8 is not completely bulletproof.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: in case of floating point math (`double`, `float`) we have to use some tolerance. `1e-8` is enough in case of small values (like digits in the example). If we have *arbitrary* values we should use `BigRational` (which is not part of standard .net library) instead of `double` (https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=BigRational)

Comment: Yep, think of (10001/10000)-(1/10001) = 1.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you very much. But its taking quiet a while; is there a mthod to only count how many solutions are possible for the given array to create the given result, without using strings? I think that takes much resources

Comment: @MrKevin: being a *brute force* solution it'll take time on *long* arrays, e.g. `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} => 100`. I've used strings since there's a convenient `DataTable.Compute` engine to evaluate formulae; if you have a better evaluator you can get rid of it. To count solutions: `int count = AllSolutions(new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 3 }, 8)).Count();`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i actually meant how with "count" how many possible ways there are to get `target`

Comment: @MrKevin: I see, so we can enumerate all these ways - `AllSolutions(new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 3 }, 8)` - but instead of printing them out, just count them: `int count = AllSolutions(new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 3 }, 8)).Count();`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko first of all, thanks for all the help, and a happy new year. The problem is, it takes way to long to perform, i randomly generate 12 digits, and i want to check, if there are multiple ways to get the same result, while testing all operators, on those digits. Now, it takes way to long to check that, and i also get StackOverFlow errors; are there any ways to make it more performant?

Comment: @MrKevin: *brute force* is not very performant, it's quite OK when you have just **4** digits (`3^4 == 81` variants to test), but can well be *slow* on **12** digits (`11^4 ~ 14000`). The main cause is `Table.Compute` which has to *parses* 14000 formulae. If you have to operate with `12` digits you should switch to a different eval and exclude parsing